# Array Sorting - Swift How Can Sort A-Z

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of pdf files (see attached screenshot) that I need to sort alphabetically. Here is the code that generates the array, can anybody suggest changes to have the array sorted?

```py
import UIKit

var pdfsArray = [String]()

class PDFListViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fm = FileManager.default
        
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!

        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        for item in items {
            if item.hasSuffix(".pdf") {
               
                pdfsArray.append(item.uppercased())
                
            }
            let sortedFiles = pdfsArray.sorted()
             pdfsArray = sortedFiles
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your image

Comment: Sorted how, what is wrong with the current solution?

Comment: You shouldn't declare your variables at global scope. Search how to pass your data from one view controller to another.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough, you can just call swift's `sort` (or `sorted`) function and provide the sort-function to sort by numeric values:

```swift
var array = ["Part 45", "Part 1", "Part 10", "Part 20", "Part 100", "Part 2"]
array.sort { st1, st2 in
    st1.compare(st2, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
}
```

Comment: How can I display just the file names without the pdf extension in the array?

Comment: Prefer using `URL` at top level instead of path `String` and you'll be able to use `deletingPathExension()` ?

Comment: @SkyCruzer using URL [resourceValues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues)'s method and get [localizedName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues/1779928-localizedname) value. If you want to hide the extension you can set the url resourceValue [hasExtensionHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues/1780013-hashiddenextension) to true

Comment: @SkyCruzer Btw when sorting files to display it to the user like the finder does, you should use the diacritic and case insensitive [localizedStandardCompare](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare)  method. **This method should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate. The exact sorting behavior of this method is different under different locales and may be changed in future releases. This method uses the current locale.**

Comment: Thank you so much all. I am new in this world of app development and I appreciate all your responses. Great working with you all.